# Algorithm to remove all objects of a tree from a list

Tags: c#, .net, algorithm, entity-framework

I have a problem where I need to remove all objects of a tree from a list.

I have a `List<String> Tags` which contains the tags in my entire system that match a certain criterion (generally starts with some search string).  I also have a root `Device` object.  The `Device` class is described as follows:

```
public class Device
{
    public int ID;
    public String Tag;
    public EntityCollection<Device> ChildDevices;
}
```

The attempt that I have made is to use a breadth first search and remove the tags from the list as each node is visited, then return whatever is leftover:

```
private List<String> RemoveInvalidTags(Device root, List<String> tags)    
{
    var queue = new Queue<Device>();
    queue.Enqueue(root);

    while (queue.Count > 0)
    {
        var device = queue.Dequeue();
        //load all the child devices of this device from DB
        var childDevices = device.ChildDevices.ToList();

        foreach (var hierarchyItem in childDevices)
            queue.Enqueue(hierarchyItem.ChildDevice);

        tags.Remove(device.Tag);
    }

    return tags;
}
```

At the moment I am visiting 2000+ device nodes and removing from a list of about 1400 tags (reduced due to the search string).  This takes about 4 secs which is far too long.

I have tried changing the list of tags to a hashset but it brings negligible speed improvements.

Any ideas of an algorithm/change that I could use to make this faster?

Comment: I dont think you can make the current approach much faster. The problem ofcourse it the load query to the database. You can however perform this in the database itself. If you need to operate on a subset of devices, you have to write something smart. Maybe a stored proc which does your current logic. Else you can just do something like: context.Devices.Select(x => x.Tag).WhereIn(tags) and remove those

Comment: how about if u dont use queue, and you do pre-order traversal ? this eliminates the queue, but your tree is more like a trie..

Comment: @DarthVader - if I understand correctly, using pre-order traversal simply changes it to DFS like ObscureRobot recommended, which you subsequently said won't solve my problem.

Comment: pre-order traversal is not like DFS, it doesnt use extra data structure. in that case, you will avoid ToList() and you will avoid queue. you can do in-order or post order, doesnt matter but not DFS or BFS. also , you might want to consider changing your tree structure. use nodes instead of your current impl.

Comment: fetching 2000+ device in too many query takes so long you should change the way of data fetching, your current code can be improved a little, but I don't think it's your problem, it's better to write a recursive store procedure ....

Comment: @DarthVader - I think you are wrong about preorder traversal not being a depth first traversal.  It does use a data structure - the stack - whether that be the call stack through recursion or explicit use of a stack object. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_traversal.

Comment: @link664 u definetely dont need an extra data structure with pre-order traversals, you use recursion, yes you have the call stack but that s not like the data structure. so yes you are right in that sense. but you should be able to use pre-order.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to guess that your tree is fairly "fat". That is, that each of your nodes has MANY children, but you don't have a lot of layers. If that is the case, give [Depth First Search](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Depth-first_search) a try. You should reach bottom quickly and then be able to start removing nodes. You still have to visit all nodes, but you won't have to store as much intermediate data as you would in BFS.

Comment: You are right, my tree is only about 5 levels deep but some nodes have 20+ children.  I'll give DFS a try and see how I go.

Comment: Doesnt sound like the solution to me since he's doing a DB request for each node. 2000+ nodes really isnt that much for traversal

Comment: it wont make a difference, your bottlneck is ToList method, IMO. why dont you use Stopwatch to find out each piece performance?

Answer (score 0):

You should definitely be using some sort of hash table (sorry, not familiar with the specifics of c#) for accessing tags.

I am curious about the process of loading the child devices from the DB.  Since you are iterating across the entire tree, you might be able to load more appropriately-sized chunks into memory.  The breadth-first search might load most of the tree into memory before starting to remove nodes from the queue (if the tree is very wide).

Comment: As mentioned, using a hashset for the tags doesn't actually make much of a difference when you factor in the pre-processing time.  The majority of time is taken up with the db call and the enqueueing of items.  I too have considered trying to load all of the needed child devices into memory but haven't come across a solution yet.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Stopwatch` to find out about the bottleneck, If you ask me

```
var childDevices = device.ChildDevices.ToList();

foreach (var hierarchyItem in childDevices)
   queue.Enqueue(hierarchyItem.ChildDevice);
```

that s your bottleneck.

Look at this [Tree implementation in C#](http://www.firatatagun.com/binary-search-tree-implementation-via-c/2011/07/10/), i hope you already know [Tree Traversals](http://www.firatatagun.com/tree-traversals/2011/05/22/).

why dont you try this?

```
foreach (var hierarchyItem in device.ChildDevices)
   queue.Enqueue(hierarchyItem.ChildDevice);
```

you dont need to convert device.ChildDevices to list, because it is already enumerable. when you convert that to list, it will be eager, which enumerable, it will be lazy.

Try that.

Comment: Yep, have used stopwatches to time it and you are correct, that is my bottleneck, although I would have thought that was fairly obvious.  The question is, how can I structure my algorithm to remove that bottleneck?

Comment: Actually, I have the convert to list in there solely for that reason.  When its lazy loaded, it takes half a second longer than when its eager loaded.

Comment: I think all the comments regarding bulk loading the child devices might be an idea but no resolution as of yet.

Answer (score 0):

It would be a good idea to instrument or profile your code to find out where most of the time is going.  An earlier comment and answer about "load query to the database" (*i.e.* `childDevices = device.ChildDevices.ToList();`) taking time may be correct, but it seems possible it might instead be
`tags.Remove(device.Tag);` that is wasting time.  A .Remove() is done for every enqueued item.  [Remove](http://www.dotnetperls.com/list-remove) takes `O(n)` time: "This method performs a linear search; therefore, this method is an O(n) operation, where n is Count." [MSDN]

That is, suppose you enqueue `m` device items, many of which have .Tag's not in your `tags` list with `n` entries.  .Remove touches every element of `tags` when it looks for a .Tag not in the list; and on average it looks at `n/2` entries to find a .Tag that is in the list, so total work is `O(m*n)`.  By contrast, work in the method below is `O(m + n)`, which typically will be hundreds of times smaller.

To sidestep the problem:

1. Preprocess `tags` list by making a hash table H corresponding to it
2. For each device.Tag, test if its hash value is in H
3. If the value is in H, add device.Tag to a dictionary D
4. After handling all device.Tag's, for each element T of `tags` list, if T is in D output T, else suppress T

Comment: As mentioned, using a hashset for the tags doesn't actually make much of a difference when you factor in the pre-processing time.  The majority of time is taken up with the db call and the enqueueing of items.